# Making the 'delete' warnings in GCC into errors

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings, gnu, gcc-warning

I want to make the following warnings in GCC into errors, however, I failed to find any documentation on which switches control them, including the [-fdiagnostics-show-option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html#index-fdiagnostics-show-option) switch.

The warnings are:

```
deleteing void * is undefined
```

and

```
possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator:
'p' has incomplete type
```

I only want to make the specified warnings into errors, not all of them.

Comment: Does it actually say *"deleteing"*? Not *"[deleting](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/delete#Verb)"*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[enabled by default]` part of the warnings (that you didn't show) indicates that there isn't any specific warning flag controlling them, so there isn't anything you can use to say `-Wno-xxx` or `-Werror=xxx`.

With GCC 4.9 you can use `-Werror=delete-incomplete` to control the second one.

Comment: So this means the only way I can handle these is to write a script which greps over the output of gcc?

Comment: Yes, or upgrade to GCC 4.9 for the second one

Comment: @tohava You can do `man gcc | grep delete` to quickly see that there isn't a switch that controls this diagnostic.

Comment: @remylabel - I was hoping this is something undocumented or that there is some alternate way I did not think of

Comment: Nope, I've checked the source code and there is no option for the "deleting void*" warning. Line 484 in cp/decl.c

Answer (score 1):

You can compile with the [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror) tag to treat warnings as errors.

Comment: I only want to make the specified warnings into errors, not all of them.

Comment: I'm not sure about that then, although what warnings are you getting that you don't want to fix?

Comment: I assume the point is to make the warnings into errors so developers can't ignore them and are forced to fix them

Comment: @JonathanWakely Basically. I was always taught to use it because you never know when something that was fine as a warning before is going to cause a problem in later updates, it's generally better just to fix all your warnings. Granted there's always a caveat, but I almost always compile with -Werror